# What is the Russian diminutive of mouse?

Tags: выбор-имени

Just a simple question as I am not sure of the right form. 
What is the Russian diminutive of mouse? *мышонок* ?

Comment: Just wondering why you've decided that  `ш` will mutate to `ж`?

Comment: Simply by mistake

Comment: Eastern slavic languages have consonant mutation in some words/roots, but it's like `к-ч-ц`, `г-ж-з`, `х-ш-с`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, ["мышонок"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) is a baby mouse so you were close, but strictly speaking diminutive is [`мышка`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_III) which is a small mouse.

Comment: @Oliver **мышка** because in Russian a mouse defaults to feminine - **мышь**

Comment: The answer is perfectly correct, but I'd like to add that it is a quite common reference to a beloved woman: "мышка моя". Very similar to "киса"(means кошка, кошечка), which is very popular amongst young men.

Answer (score 1):

There are several diminutive forms in the Russian language, like in Spanish.

Yes, the first of diminutive for mouse is ***мышка*** (small mouse), but there are possibly some other forms with gradually progressing grades of diminutive (but I think they are much rarely used for mouse itself), for example - ***мышенька*** (very small mouse) and ***мышечка*** (also very small mouse, rarely used but possible).

Comment: мышулька, мышулечка, мышуленька

Comment: Oh, yes!! There are a lot of forms in Russian!!